# Find supports of functions on a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A=k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$. Support of $f\in A$ is defined as $supp(f)=\{p\in Spec(A):f\neq 0\in A_p\}$. What are all possible supports of $f\in A$ ?

$Spec A$ is simply a line $k[x]$ with nonreduced stalk over $(x)$.
It's easy to show that:
$supp(f)=\{p\in Spec(A): ann(f)\subset p\}$. Using this I could find the following: $$supp(0)=\emptyset$$
$$supp(yf)=(x,y) \text{ such that } x\nmid f \text{ and} y\nmid f  $$
$$supp(1)=Spec(A)$$

How can I find support for arbitrary $f$ ?

Comment: Hint: since you modded out by $xy$, any polynomial can be decomposed in to $f(x)+g(y)+c$ where $c\in k$ and $f,g$ have no constant terms. What happens to each of these terms when you go to stalks?

Comment: $c\neq 0$ or $f\neq 0$ then $supp=Spec(A)$. $c=f=0$ and $g\neq0$ then $supp={(x,y)}$. $c=f=g=0$ then $supp=\emptyset$.
If I didn't make any mistakes, then could you copy paste your comment in the answer so that we can mark the question as answered?

Comment: My problem was that when I was looking for the annihilator of an element and I expressed the corresponding equation in terms of polynomials in 2 variables I couldn't proceed. The approach would be simply quotienting out one of the variables so that we get a simpler equation in single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since you modded out by $xy$, any polynomial can be decomposed in to $f(x)+g(y)+c$ where $c\in k$ and $f,g$ have no constant terms. What happens to each of these terms when you go to stalks?